# How do I get to medications in Health.app?

Tags: health.app, health-kit

In [this MacWorld article](http://www.macworld.co.uk/feature/iphone/complete-guide-apples-health-healthkit-3525196/) it shows a screenshot of Health.app with a section for medications but I can't find it in my Health.app. Was this functionality moved or removed at some point?

[image]

Comment: I guess you missed in the linked article in your OP where is says, "You will be able to create an emergency card, called the **Medical ID**, to the Health card. Your Medical ID is accessible from the Lock screen so it can be accessed in an emergency. Your medical ID Medical ID: Medical Conditions, Medical Note, Allergies and Reactions **and Medications**. ..." (bold text added by me) and it also shows a picture of it too which has the Edit link. I thought things were designed to be obvious... guess not.

Comment: @user3439894 I'm looking to track medications over time like the rest of the options in the screen shot (besides the Me option).

Comment: No, you can't do that in the current iteration of the Health app. Try a third party app like this one: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/medisafe-medication-reminder/id573916946?mt=8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot track medications in the Health app in the way you're describing. HealthKit does not have any medication data types. It's possible those screenshots were from an early/preview version of the Health app, but that feature definitely didn't make it into any shipping versions of Health.

Answer (score 2):

Access to the feature is more subtle now.

1. Launch Health.app
2. Tap 'Summary'
3. Tap your profile picture
4. Tap 'Medical ID'
5. Tap 'Edit'

[Source](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207021)

Answer (score 1):

When you open the `Health` app, look at the bottom row of tab choices.  On the far right you'll see one labeled *Medical ID*:

[image]

Tap on that and you should see a screen similar to this image:

[image]

Tap *Edit* on the top right (not shown in the picture above, I'm already in *Edit* mode).  Go down to the *Medications* section and enter whatever medicine you want in there.

Comment: I'm looking to track medications over time like the rest of the options in the screen shot (besides the Me option). Was that an option before? I want to know what happened when "Medications" is tapped in my screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that medication tracking was moved into CareKit from HealthKit.

"you’ll be able to regularly track your symptoms and medications" [CareKit Site at Apple](https://www.apple.com/researchkit/)

And at the HealthKit Site, the note on ResearchKit and CareKit at the very bottom of the page:

"giving you tools to track things like your symptoms and medications," [HealthKit Site at Apple](https://www.apple.com/ios/health/)